# Export data to csv - Every return value or collecting data to a hashtable first?

Tags: powershell

I have created a few Powershell scripts which focus on data collection. I scripted a few functions which mostly work like this:

- Connect to machine
- Get whatever data I need
- Append data to an existing csv-file

Now the export-csv is used in the functions directly. So there is no return value per se. 
Since I am still learning Powershell I stumbled across hashtables and was wondering, if it might be worth to alter my functions to collect data into hashtables instead of exporting all my variables filled with data directly.

I don't know what is best practice here. Performance isn't an issue but I think that iterating through hundreds of machines, openening a csv, write to it and then close it might not be the best in terms of I/O.

Alternatively I can imagine that storing all my collected data to a hashtable (or multiple hashtables) before outputting them might be hard on memory.

Can you help me out? What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 4):

There are two common approaches to things like this:

- Use a `foreach` loop and collect the data in a variable, then export that variable to a CSV.

  ```
  $data = foreach ($server in (Get-Content 'input.txt')) {
       # do stuff here, then build a custom object from the results
       New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
           'ComputerName' = $server
           ...
       }
  }

  $data | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
  ```
- Use a `ForEach-Object` loop where you read input from the pipeline and pass output to `Export-Csv` via the pipeline.

  ```
  Get-Content 'input.txt' | ForEach-Object {
      # do stuff here, then build a custom object from the results
      New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
          'ComputerName' = $_
          ...
      }
  } | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
  ```

The former approach provides better performance, but has the disadvantage that all data is read into memory (`foreach` loops can't write to the pipeline). If you have large amounts of data that might lead to memory exhaustion.

The latter approach is resilient against memory exhaustion because the pipeline normally handles one object at a time. Overall processing is slower than a `foreach` loop, though.

Which of these two approaches is best in a given scenario depends on the actual data you're processing.

I would not recommend putting `Export-Csv` inside your processing function, at least not without making it optional. For one thing it's not good practice from a performance point-of-view. When calling the function in a loop, the file must be opened repeatedly. It's better to open it just once and close it after all data has bee written. Also, you gain flexibility by separating processing from output. Have your function return the "raw" data, and you can do with it whatever you need (write to a CSV, display to a user, pass to another application, ...).

Have your function accept pipeline input, e.g. like this:

```
function Invoke-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        $InputObject,
        ...
    )

    Begin {
        # initialize stuff here
    }

    Process {
        $InputObject | ForEach-Object {
            # do stuff here, then build a custom object from the results
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        # cleanup goes here
    }
}
```

and you can use it in a `foreach` loop

```
$data = foreach ($server in (Get-Content 'input.txt')) {
    Invoke-Foo $server
}

$data | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

as well as a pipeline:

```
Get-Content 'input.txt' | Invoke-Foo | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

If for some reason you must have the ability to write data to a file from within the function, I'd probably modify the function like this:

```
function Invoke-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        ...
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$Append,
        ...
    )

    ...
    Process {
        $InputObject | ForEach-Object {
            # do stuff here, then build a custom object from the results
            $obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                ...
            }
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Path')) {
                $obj | Export-Csv $Path -NoType -Append:$Append.IsPresent
            } else {
                $obj
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not entirely though what I was looking for. Let me specify: Right now, instead of storing the returned data to a variable like you have shown above, my functions export the collected data directly. Export-CSV is part of my function. I am using a foreach to call this function with my provided computernames. Once the function has exported to csv, the next one will follow and so on. Is it better to store the data in a variable and then export it or use the export-csv in the function itself?

Comment: In general I wouldn't recommend appending to a file in a loop, because each time you need to open the file, skip to the end, write the data and close it again. Performance-wise it's better to open the file just once and keep it open until all data has been written. Personally I would probably remove the `Export-Csv` from the function (or at least make file output configurable via an optional parameter) and modify the function parameters so that they accept pipeline input.